# XPath Param Value Is Not Evaluating In Expression

Tags: xpath

The @Value='1' Does not seem to be evaluating in this expression below as it returns both nodes of SEventData instead of only one that has a @Value of '1'. What am I missing?

Source:

```
<CData>
<SData SKey="006" >

<SEventData SEventOID="UNS" SEventRepeatKey="2">
<FData FOID="REQUIRED" FRepeatKey="1">
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="REQUIRED" ItemGroupRepeatKey="0" 
TransactionType="Upsert">
<ItemData ItemOID="REQ" Value="0"  />
</ItemGroupData>
</FData>
</SEventData>

<SEventData SEventOID="UNS" SEventRepeatKey="3">
<FData FOID="REQUIRED" FRepeatKey="1">
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="REQUIRED" ItemGroupRepeatKey="0" 
TransactionType="Upsert">
<ItemData ItemOID="REQ" Value="1"  />
</ItemGroupData>
</FData>
</SEventData>

</SData>
</CData>
```

with expression

```
//CData[.//SData[@SKey='006']/SEventData/FData/ItemGroupData/ItemData[@ItemOID='REQ' and @Value='1']]//SEventData
```

returns both instead of one

```
Element='<SEventData SEventOID="UNS" SEventRepeatKey="2">
  <FData FOID="REQUIRED" FRepeatKey="1">
     <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="REQUIRED"
                 ItemGroupRepeatKey="0"
                 TransactionType="Upsert">
        <ItemData ItemOID="REQ" Value="0"/>
     </ItemGroupData>
  </FData>
</SEventData>'
Element='<SEventData SEventOID="UNS" SEventRepeatKey="3">
  <FData FOID="REQUIRED" FRepeatKey="1">
     <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="REQUIRED"
                 ItemGroupRepeatKey="0"
                 TransactionType="Upsert">
        <ItemData ItemOID="REQ" Value="1"/>
     </ItemGroupData>
  </FData>
</SEventData>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this XPath in order to locate what you are looking for:

```xml
//SEventData[.//FData/ItemGroupData/ItemData[@ItemOID='REQ' and @Value='1']]
```

Your current XPath expression returns the root node `//CData` containing in it the following condition: `.//SData[@SKey='006']/SEventData/FData/ItemGroupData/ItemData[@ItemOID='REQ' and @Value='1']`.
So yes, `//CData` has inside it the condition as above and when you trying to locate `//SEventData` inside that `//CData` it returns you both `//SEventData` nodes.
What you should do here is to locate `//SEventData` node itself based on your condition as I wrote at the beginning:

```xml
//SEventData[.//FData/ItemGroupData/ItemData[@ItemOID='REQ' and @Value='1']]
```